# Add onto method in parent class from inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Suppose that you have a function in the parent class, it does x and y. But now in the inherited class, you want to make the function also do z. You can't overwrite it because that would mean that the function no longer does x and y.

Here is my unity example:

This is the code in the parent class:

```
protected virtual void Start () 
{
    MyRigidBody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if(Controls.Length < 4)
        throw new System.Exception("Controls not assigned correctly");
}
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
protected void Start () 
{
    MyBase.Start();//MyBase.Start doesn't work
    BlahBlahBlah();
    Stuff();
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use "public override void"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `base` to call the base class' implementation of `Start()`. You also have to `override` the `virtual` method in the child class:

```
protected override void Start () 
{
    base.Start();
    BlahBlahBlah();
    Stuff();
}
```

You can also use template method pattern to define the skeleton of the method in the base class and provide implementation of some parts in derived classes.

```
public void Start() 
{
    MyRigidBody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if(Controls.Length < 4)
        throw new System.Exception("Controls not assigned correctly");

    DoSomethingElse();
}

protected virtual void DoSomethingElse()
{
    //can be empty in base class, derived classes provide the implementation
}
```

The `Start` method is not virtual. If you want to modify the behavior of `Start` method in derived classes, you override `DoSomethingElse()`.

Comment: Same answer at the same time :p

Answer (score 1):

Add `override` keyword.

```
protected override void Start()
{
   base.Start();
   DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here, one in your code sample and one in your understanding of how overriding works.

- `Start()` is already defined as a `protected virtual` method of the parent class. Your definition in the derived class with conflict with the parent's definition unless you declare `Start()` in your derived class as `protected override`.
- Declaring an override of a method does not preclude you from including the functionality provided by the base class's method. You can invoke the base class's definition of `Start()` by calling it using `base.Start();` Your attempt to call it via `MyBase.Start()` doesn't work because that syntax is attempting to tell the compiler to find a `static` method in `MyBase` called `Start()`, which does not exist (or at least does not in the sample you've provided.)

In short, declaring `Start()` as `protected override void` and calling the base class's version via `base.Start();` will accomplish your stated goal.